# Compare string not getting proper result in php

Tags: php

I need to compare 2 string, and need to show difference for the particular variable, i have creted below but it is not working properly, can anyone please check my code and give me proper solution for that ?

```
$template = '<div[string:class_cover_ratio]><div[string:class_2]><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" data-cbp-src="[image:thumbnail_name]" width="[string:large_width]" height="[string:large_height]"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="[image:large_name]" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="[string:title]">[string:view_larger_text]</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">[string:dish_name]</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">[string:dish_description]</div></div>';
$edited = '<div class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="4:3"><div class="cbp-caption" style=""><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" data-cbp-src="http://cubewp.axcelmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Ankimo-thum.jpg" width="400" height="300"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="http://cubewp.axcelmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Ankimo.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="Monkfish Liver, lightly garnished">View Larger</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Ankimo</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">Monkfish Liver, lightly garnished</div></div>';

function test($edited, $template) {
    $gottenValues = [];
    preg_match_all('/\[.*\]/U', $template, $names);
    $names = $names[0];
    $templateParts = preg_split('/\[.*\]/U', $template);
    foreach ($templateParts as $index => $part) {
        if ($index === 0) {
            $part = trim($part);
            $edited = trim($edited);
            $edited = substr($edited, strlen($part));
            continue;
        }
        $edited = explode($part, $edited);
        $gottenValues[trim($names[$index - 1], '[]')] = $edited[0];
        if (isset($edited[1])) {
            $edited = $edited[1];
        } else {
            $edited = "";
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($gottenValues);
    die;
}

test($edited, $template);
```

It shows me below outout

```
Array
(
    [string:class_cover_ratio] =>  class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="4:3"
    [string:class_2] =>  class="cbp-caption" style=""
    [image:thumbnail_name] => 
    [string:large_width] => 
    [string:large_height] => 
    [image:large_name] => 
    [string:title] => 
    [string:view_larger_text] => 
    [string:dish_name] => 
    [string:dish_description] => 
)
```

You can see it only works for first 2 values, for other variable it doesn't giving me any value

Comment: First thing is the code is not complete, and I see `$names = $names[0];`, only use the first element, so I guess this is the problem.

Comment: It is not a issue, i am just using that value for diffrent purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to pull the value for the image's `data-cbp-src`, you could take a different approach with [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with a loop:

```
$edited = '<img src="" alt="" data-cbp-src="http://cubewp.axcelmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/YakiTori.jpg" width="1900" height="1267"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="http://cubewp.axcelmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/YakiTori.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="View Larger">View Larger</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Yaki Tori</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">Yaki Tori</div></div>';
foreach(explode('data-cbp-src="', $edited) as $part) {
    if ($end = strpos($part, '"'))
        $urls[] = substr($part, 0, $end)
}
```

Obviously, I would need your actual, full code to provide an actual, full solution, but this would populate your `urls` array with all values for `data-cpb-src` in any elements.

Comment: i need to get result by variable name like [string:large_width] = 1900 and so for the other values

Comment: @NikulPanchal, we are going to need your actual input and expected output.

Comment: i have updated my question, now you will get proper output